# Let $S = \{y_1a_1+y_2a_2~|~-1 \leq y_1,y_2 \leq 1\}$ where $a_1 , a_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, polyhedra

Let $S = \{y_1a_1+y_2a_2~|~-1 \leq y_1,y_2 \leq 1\}$ where $a_1 , a_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Show $S$ is a polyhedron. Assume $a_1,a_2$ are linearly independent.

Now I believe this question was asked before, but Please check if my solution is ok. By set theory chasing, $$S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2~|~x = y_1a_1+y_2a_2, -1 \leq \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} \leq 1 \}$$

Write $A = (a_1 ~~~ a_2)$, then $A$ is invertible. hence we can write $S$ as $$S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2~|~x = A\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}, -1 \leq \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} \leq 1 \}$$
$$S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2~|~A^{-1}x = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}, -1 \leq \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} \leq 1 \}$$
$$S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2~|~-1 \leq A^{-1}x \leq 1\}$$

This is an intersection of 2 polyhedron, hence it is a polyhedron.

Comment: $A^{-1} x$ is a vector so that $x\in S$ iff $A^{-1}x\in [-1,1]^2$

Comment: @HKLee Because the definition of a polyhedron is in this form: $P = \{x~|~ Ax \leq b\}$, so can I do the question as such?

Comment: (1) $a_i$ is vector ? (2) In $Ax\leq b$, $A$ is $1\times 2$ matrix and $b\in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: yes $a_i$ is a vector,, $A$ is a $2$ by $2$ matrix and $b \in R^2$

Comment: If so, what does $Ax\leq b$ mean ?

Comment: $Ax \leq b$ for some $A \in m \times n$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$.